# Calculating WoW, MoM and YoY for a dimension/metric

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking for a way to calculate the WoW, MoM and YoY in the same table/report for a give dimension/metric, lets say site visitors by device type.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a reporting question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Google Data Studio?  Once linked to your Google Analytics account, you can create reports with whatever data you'd like and can individually set each graph, table, or scorecard to be compared to the time period that you specify.